# Why the data of my datatable doesn't apper when I use filter and then reload the page?

Tags: spring, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, liferay

I have a datatable with data and filter

[image]

The filter works perfecly, when I white some that doenst exists, the datable is empty, but when I reload the page the data doenest show in the datatable

[image]

This is my code

XHTML

```
<p:tab title="#{caseList['caseManagement.assignedToMe']}" id="myCaseTab">               
    <p:dataTable var="myCase" id="myCases"
    value="#{caseManagement.myWork}"
    widgetVar="myCaseTable"
    row="5" 
    paginator="true"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    currentPageReportTemplate="({currentPage} #{caseList['caseManagement.paginator.of']} {totalPages})"
    emptyMessage="#{caseList['caseManagement.emptyList']}"
    filteredValue="#{caseManagement.filteredMyWork}" 
    paginatorPosition="top">
```

BEAN

```
private List<Case> myWork = new ArrayList<Case>(); //get and set

private List<Case> work = new ArrayList<Case>(); //get and set

private int sizefilteredMyWork;  //get and set

private int sizeFilteredAllWork;  //get and set

private List<Case> filteredMyWork;  //get and set

private List<Case> filteredAllWorks; //get and set

private Case selectedCase; //get and set

public CaseManagementBean()
{
    init();

}

public void init()
{

    addElementToMyWork();
    addElementToWork();

    setSizeFilteredAllWork(work.size());
    setSizefilteredMyWork(myWork.size());
}
```

How can I fix it?

### **Edit**

```
public void addElementToMyWork()
{
    // FIXME: llenado de lista temporal hasta acceder a oriden de datos
    getMyWork().add(
            new Case(null, "John Smith Address", null, null, null, "Collect Evidence", "Manual Investigation", "Company #1",
                    null, null, null, null));
    getMyWork().add(
            new Case(null, "3rd Division Incorrect Drivers License N° 77288282", null, null, null, "Decision Making",
                    "Manual Investigation", "Company #7", null, null, null, null));
    getMyWork().add(
            new Case(null, "Double Fraud Alert Cloned Address 8892911", null, null, null, "Evidence", "Manual Investigation",
                    "Company #1", null, null, null, null));
    getMyWork().add(
            new Case(null, "Miami Gateway Credit Fault", null, null, null, "Evidence", "Manual Investigation", "Company #6",
                    null, null, null, null));
}

public void addElementToWork()
{
    // FIXME: llenado de lista temporal hasta acceder a oriden de datos
    getWork().add(
            new Case(null, "John Smith Address", null, null, "Calvin Smith", "Collect Evidence", "Manual Investigation",
                    "Company #1", null, null, null, null));
    getWork().add(
            new Case(null, "3rd Division Incorrect Driver Licence Nº 77288282", null, null, "John Snack", "Collect Evidence",
                    "Manual Investigation", "Company #6", null, null, null, null));
    getWork().add(
            new Case(null, "Double Fraud Alert Cloned Address 8892911", null, null, "-", "Collect Evidence",
                    "Manual Investigation", "Company #4", null, null, null, null));
    getWork().add(
            new Case(null, "Miami Gateway Credit Fault", null, null, "Rajesh Bonganay", "Decision Making",
                    "Manual Investigation", "Company #7", null, null, null, null));

}
```

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar ViewScope

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I just edited the post, you can see know, but basicly I created fake data of Case then I add it to ``List myWork``

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I use Spring Framework so I dont need the ``@PostConstruct``. You can see the ``init()`` methof is inside of contructor so when the bean is created call that method.
if I use F5 or crtl+f5 happend the same problem. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is use only one list for display and filter

so you must delete

`filteredValue="#{caseManagement.filteredMyWork}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the session (or viewstate) prior to populating it in your event handler for the filter. Maybe when you refresh data in the table is being cached (or lack of data in this case).